# Auth0 and Google API, access token expired, howto write files to Google Drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, access-token, auth0

I've written an online converter and integrated Auth0 to my website. What I'm trying to achieve is to auto-upload the converted file to the Google Drive of a logged in user. I set up Google oauth in Auth0 and everything seemed to work fine.

The problem is, Google's `access_token` expires after 60min and I don't have a `refresh_token`. Therefore, the user needs to log in via the Google Login-page again. That is not, what I want, because the user is in fact logged in way longer than just 60min on my site, but Google refuses API-calls (because the Google token expired).

I know I can request a `refresh_token` by setting `access_type=offline` but this will add the permission `Have offline access`. I don't want that, I just want to upload data to the user's Drive, if he clicked the convert button on my page. I don't want to ask the users for permissions I don't need. If I (as a user) would link my Google account on a similar page and the tool asks for offline access I wouldn't approve, to be honest - the permission sounds like the tool creator can do whatever he wants with your account whenever he wants... There are many tools out there that have write access to a user's Drive without asking for offline access and with one single login until the user revokes the permission. How is that done?

Is there a way to make Google API calls **without** asking for offline access and **without** forcing the user to approve the app (that is already approved by him) again and again every 60min?

Thanks in advance,
phlo

Comment: Where did you find to add requesting offline access? I'm using Auth0 and lock with Angular2 and have been trying to find a way to do that.

Comment: -  https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token#obtain-a-refresh-token
-  https://auth0.com/forum/t/get-google-refresh-token/4674/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

**Prerequirements**

1. Enable `Use Auth0 instead of the IdP to do Single Sign On` in your client's Dashboard
2. Create a new Angular-route to handle the silent login callback (e.g. `/sso`)
3. Add

   ```
   $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function() {
       if ($location.path().indexOf("sso") == -1) {
           authService.relogin(); //this is your own service
       }
   });
   ```

   to your run-function and set the `callbackURL` in `angularAuth0Provider.init()` to your new Angular-route (`<YOUR_DOMAIN>/sso`). Add this URL to your accepted callbacks in the Auth0 dashboard - this won't end in an infinite loop, because the `locationChangeStart`-event won't call `authService.relogin()` for this route
4. Add `$window.close();` to the controller of the Angular-route (`/sso`) to auto-close the popup
5. Authenticate the user via Auth0 and save the timestamp and the Auth0-`access_token` somewhere

**On reload:**

Check, if the Auth0-token is still valid in `authService.relogin()`. If not, the user has to login again either way. If the token is valid and the Google token is about to expire (check this with the saved timestamp to prevent  unnecessary API calls) check for SSO-data and login silently, if present

```
    /* ... */
    if (validToken && googleExpired) {
        angularAuth0.getSSOData(function (err, data) {
            var lastUsedConnection = data.lastUsedConnection;
            var connectionName = (_.isUndefined(lastUsedConnection) ? undefined : lastUsedConnection.name);
            var isGoogle = (_.isUndefined(connectionName) ? false : connectionName == "google-oauth2");
            if (!err && data.sso && isGoogle) {
                authManager.authenticate();
                localStorage.setItem("last-relogin", new Date().getTime());
                angularAuth0.signin({
                    popup: true,
                    connection: data.lastUsedConnection.name
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Now you will find a fresh Google `access_token` for this user (without asking for offline access)

---

Resources:

- https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs/03-session-handling
- https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs/11-sso

Answer (score 0):

By asking for offline access you are requesting a refresh token.   Google is going to tell the user that you are requesting offline access.     You can request something without telling the user what they are authorizing.

No there is no way to request a refresh token without displaying that message.   Nor is there a way for you to change the message it's a standard Google thing.

Comment: That makes sense. But I have several tools linked to my own Google Account, for example Thunderbird - only with the "Gmail" permission, no offline access. If I open Thunderbird I never get asked to grant permission or login again - it just works. How is that done? Why is Thunderbird able to make API calls without having a refresh token and without prompting the user to login again?

Comment: Gmail is special you can also go through the SMTP server.   But I don't know anything about thunderbird besides that it was once a really weird TV show cant help

Comment: I also have tools with Drive permission linked and they don't ask me to login or re-grant everything.

Comment: Wouldn't just calling the `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` endpoint with `prompt=none` solve this problem, since the users are still online and active? Using Auth0 maybe hinders you from doing this directly though. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, the call fails with `interaction_required`. No matter if I try to reauthenticate via my Auth0-API or your posted link.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to make Google API calls without asking for offline access and without forcing the user to approve the app (that is already approved by him) again and again every 60min?**

Yes there are ways, but it depends on the specifics of your use case. For example, is your code in Java/php/etc running on a server, or is it JavaScript running in the browser?

Running your auth in the browser is probably the simplest solution as the Google library (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication) does all the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Clientside is Angular and server nodejs. The authorization happens on the client side and it would be great to call the API from the server but that is not a must. Thanks for the link.

Comment: In that case it's all really simple. You can use the Google JS library, or https://github.com/timdream/google-oauth2-web-client to generate an access token. If/when it expires, the libraries can request a new one in the background without the user seeing any UI. Once you have an access token, you can use it from the client or send it up to your server - it works equally well from both sources.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great. I will give it a try. :)